# React: How to add HTMLElement?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to wrap an external library, that returns an HTMLElement object, in a React component.

Right now, I am simply defining a ref and appending the object like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.externalLibrary = new ExternalLibrary()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.externalLibrary()
      .then(contents => this.div.appendChild(contents))
  }
  render() {
    <div ref={div => this.div = div} />
  }
}
```

But AFAIU that means that that part of the DOM will not be managed by React. What would be the proper way to add the HTMLElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let self= this;
    this.externalLibrary()
      .then(contents => self.setState({contents}))
  }
  render() {
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.contents}} />
      }
```

Comment: Hmm, that just prints `[object HTMLElement]`. It works with `{__html: this.state.contents.innerHTML}` but that seems to do the same as just calling appendChild(), i.e. React does not see this part of the DOM.

Comment: make sure that the contents containe the html text because i have no idea what the external libraries does

Comment: The external library returns a Custom Element / WebComponent as a HTMLElement object. I am looking for a way to add this to the DOM in a way that React knows about it - sorta like ReactDOM.render(contents, div), which does not work because apparently the render() method doesn't accept HTMLElement objects.

Comment: i don't understand why the dangerouslySetInnerHTML won't work then ?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, dangerouslySetInnerHTML did indeed work, my problems were related to Shadow DOM but that's a different story. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` safe to use in production or no? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 Maybe a little late but according to the docs: "You can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous". It's safe to use, despite the name, however it opens up the possibility for XSS in some cases since the html isn't validated in any way.

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` sets the `innerHTML`, not the child `HTMLElement`. The question asks how to mount an existing DOM element (eg created via `document.createElement`), not how to set the `innerHTML` of a React element.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question. It might happen to work in their case but it will not preserve the specific `HTMLElement` instance and that is what the question is.